# Synchronize (not just view) calendar events across multiple Exchange accounts?

Tags: sync, calendar, exchange-2010, exchange-2007

I have multiple Microsoft Exchange accounts. One is my main account (call it me@abc.com); two others belong to clients that I support, and they have they own domains and their own distinct instances of Exchange (call the accounts me@123.com and me@456.com). Is it possible to enter a calendar event (say, a meeting) in my main Exchange account (me@abc.com) and have that event automatically show up in the Exchange calendars associated with me@123.com and me@456.com? My goal is to keep the calendars properly synchronized so that clients at those distinct companies can look at my calendars and know when I'm available for meetings. Right now, I create a meeting in the calendar associated with the me@abc.com accoutn and then I have to mail invitations to myself at me@123.com and me@456.com.  Then I have to go in and accept all those meetings, turn off the default reminder times, set this one or that as Private, etc--and all that's a pain.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a server fault question because this is quite possible using Exchanges publish to html/ical feature.  BUT, your admin has to enable cause I'm pretty sure it is off by default.

If it IS enabled, basically the two of you will publish and sync a copy of your calendar to a third source, like Google Calendars.

Answer (score 0):

I am in a similar situation with a non-Exchange platform. What I have taken to doing, and this is not an automatic sync, is to invite myself to every meeting I schedule, and to forward invitations that I receive to the alternate accounts. The net effect is that my calendars all look the same.

Zimbra does offer me the option of auto-forwarding invitations between the accounts, but I am afraid that I will create a loop if it turn it on.

So it sounds like a hassle, but it really isn't so bad.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider something like [OggSync](http://oggsync.com/index.php/documentation-for-outlook-add-in/detailed-feature-chart-for-outlook/).  It might not be ideal for your situation, but I don't really think that anything is.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for a solution of synchronizing two exchange accounts (emails, calendars, tasks) and finally came across this app: [CB Exchange Server Sync](https://www.connecting-software.com/cb-exchange-server-sync/)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. First, fix your link. Second, read [how to recommend software in an answer](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers) and update your answer to include how someone might use it (and why).